# Using check-style but unsure of some of the errors

Tags: checkstyle

I am using checkstyle to run through my code.

It is highlighting a comment  "* @throws Exception the exception". 
It is showing the following warning "Method Javadoc: Unused @throws tag for 'Exception'." connected to the comment.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of fixing the problem:

- Remove that comment as most probably method do not declare `throws Exception`
- Disable option [validateThrows](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod) if you don't care about `@throws` tag validation